# How to set VS Code SQLTools format settings to match DataGrip SQL format settings?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code, sqltools

I'm trying to format my SQL code on VSCode SQLTools to match other team members using DataGrip with Webstorm onto VScode SQLTools but having no luck matching the SQL formatting without installing node modules (repo is for metrics).
Does anyone have a Settings.json for SQLTools or a VSCode extension that matches DataGrip SQL formatting?

This is formatting in DataGrip

```
WITH timeRange(unix_start_time, unix_end_time) AS (VALUES (1663048800, 1663135199))
```

changes to when formatting in SQLTools

```
WITH timeRange(unix_start_time, unix_end_time) AS (
  VALUES (1663048800, 1663135199)
)
```

Comment: I never got to it unfortunately @NikhilShinday. I feel it was something to do with another extension like prettier that may have been causing the problem but never figured out